# What is the best practice to create corresponding derived class according to user input?

Tags: c++, design-patterns

Currently, I have an interface and several concrete implementation class, and I got `string` type user input.
I want to `new` corresponding class according to user input. What is the best practice to do these stuff?

It seems that the "factory patten" can be used for this. Now, I use an `enum`, an `unordered_function` and a specific function to handle it, the code is like below:

```
class IStrategy{};
class A : public IStrategy{};
class B : public IStrategy{};
class C : public IStrategy{};
class D : public IStrategy{};

enum StrategyEnum
{
    A = 0,
    B, 
    C,
    D,
};

const std::unordered_map<std::string, StrategyEnum> ms_lut{
    {"A", A},
    {"B", B},
    {"C", C},
    {"D", D}};

Strategy* get_strategy(StrategyEnum s)
{
    Strategy* s;
    switch(s)
    {
        case A:
            s = new A;
            break;
        case B:
            s = new B;
            break;
        case C:
            s = new C;
            break;
        case D:
            s = new C;
            break;
        default:
            cerr << "Unsupported strategy!" << endl;
    }
    return s;
}
```

What's more, in my current situation, all derived class have the same constructor parameter, what if different class has different constructor parameter?

Comment: I think templated classes (possible combined with the Curiously Recurring Template Pattern) might be the best, most straightforward way to go.

Comment: Where would you get the constructor parameters *from* if they differed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear how the `enum` is helping you here:

1. It seems like duplication, as it's basically doing a translation that the factory could (so you have one translation of user input to enum, and one translation of enum to class)
2. It constricts you to use use only things that can be enumerated (e.g., you can't pass now to the ctor "everything except the last 3 digits from the user input", because that's not something that's enumerable).

---

Instead, how about making the factory depend on the user input? You could do very versatile stuff:

```
Strategy* get_strategy(const string &s)
{
    // If the input is "foo", return A{}
    if(s == "foo")
       return new A{};

    // If the input starts with "bar", return B{s}
    if(s.substr(0, 3) == "bar")
       return new B{s}

    // etc.
```

Comment: There is a runtime cost to the above design: by presuming structure (fixed strings) in your string-to-strategy mapping, the compiler can automatically build a binary-tree.  With the above, any such optimization had to be done by hand.  Plus, the above is code-driven logic, not data-driven logic, so it makes testing and verification extra annoying.

Comment: @Yakk Thanks for the comment. I completely agree with the 2nd point, and have erased the relevant part. As to the 1st point - can't say I see why. a. In code involving memory allocation and object creation, I can't really imagine the savings would be measurable (note that the alternative has a hash lookup too, moreover). b. I don't see why the (current) code is less data driven (perhaps it was less so before the part I erased).

Comment: I use an `enum` because I want to seperate the user-input validation logic and the actual class creation. I think that through an `enum`, only validated user input would be translated to `enum`.

Comment: @Alaya I think the validation concerns are orthogonal to where they take place. At some point you have to perform validation: either when you translate things to an enum, or when you create objects. However, my point is that if you have the enum on the way, then 1. you'll end up having "repetitive" pairs of code (which I think is a [smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell)), and 2. you'll be constrained, post validation, to use only things which can be enumerated - not all things in the world are. Good luck in any case.

Answer (score 1):

How far do you want to go?

We could create a compile-time mapping from strategies, a magic switch that maps run time to compile time values, a layered input processing system that intelligently picks between various meta-factories, etc.

Me?  If your enum and your strategies are tightly coupled, make it tighter:

```
class IStrategy{};
enum class StrategyEnum {
  A = 0,
  B, 
  C,
  D,
  Strategy_Count, // must be LAST in enum
};
template<StrategyEnum> class Strategy;

template<> class Strategy<A>: public IStrategy {};
template<> class Strategy<B>: public IStrategy {};
template<> class Strategy<C>: public IStrategy {};
template<> class Strategy<D>: public IStrategy {};
```

Then if you have a magic switch hanging around, `get_strategy` can be auto-written for you.

```
IStrategy* pStrat = magic_switch( eStrat, [&](auto strat)->IStrategy* {
  constexpr StrategyEnum e = static_cast<StrategyEnum>(static_cast<std::size_t>(strat));
  return new Strategy<e>{};
});
```

which has less code duplication than the switch/case you wrote, especially if the number of types starts to get bigger.  But the boilerplate of `magic_switch` is large and complex and tricky.

Now, if your strategies need different data, you need a way to provide it to them.  The easiest way would be to produce a data-source structure of some kind from which each can get the data they need.

Then either they have a constructor that takes a data source, or you write a function that takes the data-source, gets the data it needs, then constructs the object.

---

However, the #1 rule is "you probably won't need it".  Figure out what you need.  Hide the details.  Implement and ship.  All of the above is serious over-engineering.

---

Here is a magic switch:

```
template<std::size_t count>
struct magic_switch_t {
private:
  template<std::size_t I>
  using Index = std::integral_constant<std::size_t, I>;
  template<class F>
  using R=std::result_of_t<F&(Index<0>)>;

  template<class F, std::size_t...Is>
  R<F> invoke( std::index_sequence<Is...>, std::size_t i, F&& f ) const {
    using pf = R<F>(*)(F&);
    pf table[] = {
      +[](F& f)->R<F>{ return std::forward<F>(f)(Index<Is>{}); }...
    };
    return table[i](f);
  };
public:
  template<class F>
  R<F> operator()( std::size_t i, F&& f) const {
    return invoke( std::make_index_sequence<count>{}, i, std::forward<F>(f) );
  }
};
```

which takes a count and an index and a lambda, then invokes the lambda with the compile-time value of the index (assuming it is less than count) and returns the result.

Using this you can convert the run-time value of what enum the user picked, to a compile-time known enum value.  Then you can map that compile-time known enum value to the proper constructor code.

In effect, this lets you synthesize the `get_strategy` boilerplate.

It is overengineering, but an option.

Note that some otherwise fine C++ compilers fail on the above legal code.  On them, you need to write the lambda used in `invoke` manually as a non-anonymous type.  A bit of extra boilerplate, but nothing tricky.

Comment: If the strategy is input by user, then it should be known at runtime, so I don't understand how could the transformation could happen at compile time?

Comment: @alaya I found this old answer when self-googling for an implementation of `magic_switch`, and realized I never told you I edited the above answer with an answer to your question.  So this comment is just to ping you.